# Independent random variables' equivalence proof

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

I'm trying to prove a result from probability theory. First of all, I'm using the following definition:

> **Definition:** Given a random vector $(X,Y)$ with induced probability function $\Bbb P$, consider the two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with marginal probability functions $\Bbb P_X$ and $\Bbb P_Y$ respectively. We say $X$ and $Y$ are independent if $\Bbb P(A\times B)=\Bbb P_X(A)\Bbb P_Y(B)\quad\forall A,B\in\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$, where $\cal B(\Bbb R)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Bbb R$.

In the previous paragraph there's an abuse of notation, since $\Bbb P(A\times B)$ actually means $\Bbb P((X,Y)\in A\times B)$, and something similar for $\Bbb P_X$ and $\Bbb P_Y$.

I've been trying to prove the following:

> Given a random vector $(X,Y)$, $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $F(x,y)=F_X(x)F_Y(y)\quad\forall x,y\in\Bbb R$, where $F$, $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are the joint distribution function of $(X,Y)$ and the marginal distribution functions respectively.

The right implication is easy to prove; I'm stuck with the left one.

I've been able to show that if $\Bbb P(A\times B)=\Bbb P_X(A)\Bbb P_Y(B)$ for some $A,B\in\cal B(\Bbb R)$, then it follows $\Bbb P(A^\mathsf{c}\times B)=\Bbb P_X(A^\mathsf{c})\Bbb P_Y(B)$, $\quad\Bbb P(A\times B^\mathsf{c})=\Bbb P_X(A)\Bbb P_Y(B^\mathsf{c})\quad$ and $\quad\Bbb P(A^\mathsf{c}\times B^\mathsf{c})=\Bbb P_X(A^\mathsf{c})\Bbb P_Y(B^\mathsf{c})$.

I also proved that if $\Bbb P((A_1\cup A_2)\times B)=\Bbb P_X(A_1\cup A_2)\Bbb P_Y(B)$ for any $A_1,A_2,B\in\cal B(\Bbb R)$, then $\Bbb P((\cup_{i\in I} A_i)\times B)=\Bbb P_X(\cup_{i\in I} A_i)\Bbb P_Y(B)$ for any $B\in\cal B(\Bbb R)$ and any finite family $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ with every $A_i\in\cal B(\Bbb R)$; this is just using induction. From there I proved that it also follows $\Bbb P((\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)\times B)=\Bbb P_X(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)\Bbb P_Y(B)$ for any $B\in\cal B(\Bbb R)$ and any countable family $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with every $A_n\in\cal B(\Bbb R)$.

As you can see, the only thing I couldn't prove is: if $\Bbb P(A_1\times B)=\Bbb P_X(A_1)\Bbb P_Y(B)$ and $\Bbb P(A_2\times B)=\Bbb P_X(A_2)\Bbb P_Y(B)$ for some $A_1,A_2,B\in\cal B(\Bbb R)$, then $\Bbb P((A_1\cup A_2)\times B)=\Bbb P_X(A_1\cup A_2)\Bbb P_Y(B)$. I could prove it if I were able to prove first that in that case we have $\Bbb P((A_1\cap A_2)\times B)=\Bbb P_X(A_1\cap A_2)\Bbb P_Y(B)$, but I'm stuck there too.

Do you have any suggestions for proving the intersection part? Or maybe the union part (that's the really important one) can be proved without the intersection part; how? Any hints for any part would be deeply appreciated.

I also wanted to make sure I'm contemplating the proof structure correctly. My thinking is as follows: If I prove the union part, as I said I can prove the finite union, and then the countable union. A similar proof would be done (not really) to show we can also do this unions for the random variable $Y$ and, after that, for both of them at the same time (I think I don't need this last part). So I'll have that $F(x,y)=F_X(x)F_Y(y)\quad x,y\in\Bbb R$ implies that the independence of random variables in given sets is conserved under complement and countable union of those sets (or just one of them). Since $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(y)$ are just $\Bbb P_X((-\infty,x])$ and $\Bbb P_Y((-\infty,y])$ respectively, and the intervals $\{(-\infty,a]:a\in\Bbb R\}$ generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Bbb R$, the result follows. Is this reasoning correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no abuse of notation.